# React Js custom accordion, open one item at the time

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an accordion in React formed of a `row` component which is looped inside a `body` parent component. In the `row` I'm toggling the state `showDetails` to show/hide the `details` for each row, effectively opening the accordion item. But, since the state is for each row, how do I close one accordion item when I open another one?

Body:

```
export default class Body extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const {modelProps, showInfo, linkedRow} = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="c-table__body">
        {this.props.model.map(
          (subModel, i) =>
            linkedRow ?
              <LinkedRow
                key={`${i}`}
                model={subModel}
                modelProps={modelProps}
              />
              :
              <Row
                key={`${i}_${subModel.username}`}
                model={subModel}
                modelProps={modelProps}
                showInfo={showInfo}
                handleStatusChanged={this.props.handleStatusChanged}
              />
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Row:

```
class Row extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      userId: '',
      showDetails: false,
      showModal: false,
      status: '',
      value: '',
      showInfo: false
    };
      render() {
        const { model, modelProps, showInfo } = this.props;
        return (
          <div className="c-table__row">
            <div className="c-table__row-wrapper">
              {modelProps.map((p, i) => (
                <div className={`c-table__item ${this.isStatusCell(model[p]) ? model[p] : p}`} key={i}>{this.isStatusCell(model[p]) ? this.toTitleCase(model[p]) : model[p]}</div>
              ))}

              {showInfo ? (
                <div className="c-table__item c-table__item-sm">
                  <a
                    name="view-user"
                    onClick={this.showDetailsPanel}
                    className={this.state.showDetails ? 'info showing' : 'info'}
                  >
                    <Icon yicon="Expand_Cross_30_by_30" />
                  </a>
                </div>
              ) : (
                ''
              )}
            </div>
            {this.state.showDetails ? (<ConnectedDetails user={model} statusToggle={this.handleStatusChange}/>) : null}
          </div>
        );
      }

}

export default Row;
```

Not really sure how to approach this, maybe something in the `body` that check is there's any `row` open according to the `showDetails` state in the rows?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The approach is to lift the state of which `<Row />` is open to the `<Body />` component.
Also the method that switch between opened `<Row />` is on the `<Body />` component.

```
toggleOpen = (idx) => {
 this.setState({ openRowIndex: idx });
}
```

then when you rendered your `<Row />`s you can pass a prop isOpen:

```
<Row
   key={`${i}_${subModel.username}`}
   model={subModel}
   modelProps={modelProps}
   showInfo={showInfo}
   handleStatusChanged={this.props.handleStatusChanged}
   isOpen={this.state.openRowIndex === i}
   onToggle={_ => this.toggleOpen(i)}
/>
```